# How to solve "out of memory" error in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, out-of-memory

I was trying to create patches of the images from my dataset. This is my code:

```py
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):  
    dirname = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    if dirname == 'images':   #Find all 'images' directories
        images = os.listdir(path)  #List of all image names in this subdirectory
        for i, image_name in enumerate(images):  
            if image_name.endswith(".tif"):   #Only read jpg images...
               
                image = cv2.imread(path+"/"+image_name, 1)  #Read each image as BGR
                SIZE_X = (image.shape[1]//patch_size)*patch_size #Nearest size divisible by our patch size
                SIZE_Y = (image.shape[0]//patch_size)*patch_size #Nearest size divisible by our patch size
                image = Image.fromarray(image)
                image = image.crop((0 ,0, SIZE_X, SIZE_Y))  #Crop from top left corner
                #image = image.resize((SIZE_X, SIZE_Y))  #Try not to resize for semantic segmentation
                image = np.array(image)             
       
                #Extract patches from each image
                print("Now patchifying image:", path+"/"+image_name)
                patches_img = patchify(image, (patch_size, patch_size, 3), step=patch_size)  #Step=256 for 256 patches means no overlap
        
                for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
                    for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
                        
                        single_patch_img = patches_img[i,j,:,:]
                        
                        #Use minmaxscaler instead of just dividing by 255. 
                        single_patch_img = scaler.fit_transform(single_patch_img.reshape(-1, single_patch_img.shape[-1])).reshape(single_patch_img.shape)
                        
                        #single_patch_img = (single_patch_img.astype('float32')) / 255. 
                        single_patch_img = single_patch_img[0] #Drop the extra unecessary dimension that patchify adds.                               
                        image_dataset.append(single_patch_img)
```

But it shows the error "out of memory" and immediately shuts down. I am using 32GB ram and 1660Ti GPU. The images are 5000X5000 pixels and the size of my dataset is 12.7GB.

Comment: You cannot resolve it. You just have to compress them

Answer (score 2):

If you load a file in a Jupyter notebook and store its content in a variable, the underlying Python process will keep the memory for this data allocated as long as the variable exists and the notebook is running. Python's garbage collector will free the memory again (in most cases) if it detects that the data is not needed anylonger. This is the case if it is deleted, e.g. by using del, if the variable is overwritten with something else or if it goes out of scope (a local variable at the end of a function).

If you are storing large files in (different) variables over weeks, the data will stay in memory and eventually fill it up. In this case you actually might have to shutdown the notebook manually or use some other method to delete the (global) variables.

A completely different reason for the same kind of problem might be a bug in Jupyter. These type of bugs are called memory leak and often occur in server processes running for a long time. Even if they are less likely to happen in Python, there are some bug reports for Jupyter. In this case, the only work around might be restarting the Jupyter process. In other cases I would recommend doing so.